# How to implement a Timer class in Java?

Tags: java, timer

Recently, I have been developing some android apps and I found that `android.os.Handler` class is very suitable for implementing a .NET Timer (By that I mean `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` and `System.Timers.Timer`).

If you don't know what a .NET timer is, it's a timer that can be stopped, started at any time and its interval can be changed any time.

So I did the following:

```
import android.os.Handler;

public class Timer {
    private Handler handler;
    private boolean paused;

    private int interval;

    private Runnable task = new Runnable () {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (!paused) {
                runnable.run ();
                Timer.this.handler.postDelayed (this, interval);
            }
        }
    };

    private Runnable runnable;

    public int getInterval() {
        return interval;
    }

    public void setInterval(int interval) {
        this.interval = interval;
    }

    public void startTimer () {
        paused = false;
        handler.postDelayed (task, interval);
    }

    public void stopTimer () {
        paused = true;
    }

    public Timer (Runnable runnable, int interval, boolean started) {
        handler = new Handler ();
        this.runnable = runnable;
        this.interval = interval;
        if (started)
            startTimer ();
    }
}
```

And it came out ok. Also, this one runs on the UI thread which means that I can use this to change graphical stuff. (I mainly use timers for those stuff)

However, this only works for android though. If I want to make a "traditional" java program, I have to use the stuff in the JDK. So I tried the following:

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class DotNetTimer {
    private Timer timer;
    private boolean paused;
    private int interval;

    private TimerTask task = new TimerTask () {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (!paused)
                runnable.run();
        }
    };

    public Runnable runnable;

    public int getInterval() {
        return interval;
    }

    public void setInterval(int interval) {
        this.interval = interval;
        if (!paused) {
            timer.cancel();
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, interval, interval);
        }
    }

    public void startTimer () {
        timer.cancel();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, interval);
    }

    public void stopTimer () {
        paused = true;
    }

    public DotNetTimer (Runnable runnable, int interval, boolean started) {
        timer = new Timer ();
        this.runnable = runnable;
        this.interval = interval;
        if (started) {
            paused = false;
            startTimer ();
        }
    }
}
```

And I use this code to test it:

```
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class MyTestingClass {

    static DotNetTimer timer;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable () {
            int count = 0;

            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (count < 5) {
                    count++;
                    out.println("Hello" + count);
                } else {
                    timer.stopTimer();
                }
            }

        };

        timer = new DotNetTimer (r, 2000, true);
    }

}
```

However, an `IllegalStateException` was thrown in the start timer method. I did some research on that and I found that `java.util.Timer` cannot be restarted after `cancel()`. And I know what you're saying, "why do you call `cancel()` in the `startTimer()` method?" If I don't call `cancel()`, the timer would have 2 tasks running when I call `startTimer()` when the timer is already started.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that there is a class in Android called `Handler` which can execute code with a delay. So I made use of this class to create a timer!

```
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Timer implements Comparable<Timer> {
    private Handler handler;
    private boolean paused;
    private TextView text;

    private int minutes;
    private int seconds;

    private final Runnable timerTask = new Runnable () {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (!paused) {
                seconds++;
                if (seconds >= 60) {
                    seconds = 0;
                    minutes++;
                }

                text.setText (Timer.this.toString ());
                Timer.this.handler.postDelayed (this, 1000);
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public String toString () {
        if (Integer.toString (seconds).length () == 1) {
            return minutes + ":0" + seconds;
        } else {
            return minutes + ":" + seconds;
        }
    }

    public void startTimer () {
        paused = false;
        handler.postDelayed (timerTask, 1000);
    }

    public void stopTimer () {
        paused = true;
    }

    public void resetTimer () {
        stopTimer ();
        minutes = 0;
        seconds = 0;
        text.setText (toString ());
    }

    public Timer (TextView text) {
        this.text = text;
        handler = new Handler ();
    }

    public Timer (TextView text, String parseString) {
        this (text);
        String[] splitString = parseString.split (":");
        minutes = Integer.parseInt (splitString[0]);
        seconds = Integer.parseInt (splitString[1]);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(@NonNull Timer another) {
        int numberOfSeconds = seconds + minutes * 60;
        int anotherNumberOfSeconds = another.seconds + another.minutes * 60;

        return ((Integer)numberOfSeconds).compareTo (anotherNumberOfSeconds);
    }
}
```

And it has a really simple interface. Very easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

From `cancel()` method in Timer class

> Terminates this timer, discarding any currently scheduled tasks. Does
>   not interfere with a currently executing task (if it exists). Once a
>   timer has been terminated, its execution thread terminates gracefully,
>   and no more tasks may be scheduled on it.
>
> Note that calling this method from within the run method of a timer
>   task that was invoked by this timer absolutely guarantees that the
>   ongoing task execution is the last task execution that will ever be
>   performed by this timer.
>
> This method may be called repeatedly; the second and subsequent calls
>   have no effect.

so, internal thread of Timer is one-shot, you need to instantiate a new `Timer` object

You can check original source code of Timer class to understand (or replicate as you wish) how it really works

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Timer.java